# Windows Forms, 'textbox.Lines' equivalent in Windows Presentation Foundation

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using a WPF text box in a Windows Forms. Most of it is working. One thing that is not there is 'textBox.Lines' I don't see 'Lines' in the intellisense. What is the option I need.

Windows Forms currently 
`string[] file3 = textBox1.Lines;`A very simple way to get the textBox content to an array.

Reason this is not a duplicate question. This is asking about an equivalent command in WPF to that in WF, and is specifically talking about an array[]

Comment: Write a trivial extension method based on Johannes’ answer (but use `List<String>`). You probably don’t really need an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these code to get your collection :

```
StringCollection lines = new StringCollection();
int lineCount = textBox.LineCount;

for (int line = 0; line < lineCount; line++)
    lines.Add(textBox.GetLineText(line));
```

Comment: The current useage is `string[] file3 = textBox1.Lines;` nothing to do with line counting

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. How does that give me an array?

Answer (score 0):

You could split the `TextBox.Text` using `"\n"`.
With `StringSplitOptions.None` to return all the lines, including the empty ones.

```
string[] lines = TextBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

With `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to return the non empty lines only.

```
string[] lines = TextBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This will give you the same array that `TextBoxBase.Lines()` returns.
Of course, this array represent, as usual, the original text disposition, not the wrapped lines, if `TextBox1.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;`

Comment: It appears that textBox.Lines of Windows Forms, which puts all the lines of a textBox into an array, is not available in a WPF textBox. So I marked this as the answer as that is now the only way to get the textBox text to an array.

Comment: I don't have the needed brownie points for my checking of the answer to register publicly.